# Simple 2D graphics in Objective C (GNUStep)

Tags: objective-c, opengl, 2d, sdl

I'm creating a simple agent-based modeling-framework and I'd like to provide some very simple visualizations. Nothing too fancy, and mainly just 2D graphics. Can I use OpenGL or SDL with Objective C on GNUStep? How would I go about doing this? I tried looking for some examples, but couldn't find any. Will C examples that use OpenGL or SDL play nice with Objective C?

Comment: @theAmateurProgrammer Is Core Animation available on GNUStep?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use OpenGL on GNUstep but if you just want 2D graphics, you can simply use its graphics operators. Take a look at Cocoa Drawing Guide, The code are pretty much the same. They are much easier to use than OpenGL; can draw curves and more.

https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CocoaDrawingGuide/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40003290

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you want OpenGL es. here is a link to a basic tutorial http://www.raywenderlich.com/3664/opengl-es-2-0-for-iphone-tutorial

Comment: Those examples seem to be geared to the iPhone. Will they work with GNUStep?

Comment: There seem to be some Obj-C 2.0 features like `@property`. Not sure if they are available in GNUStep yet. They always seem a few steps behind Apple.